# Java - Loading Periods help? String

Tags: java, string

I can't think of a correct way to have a method that would return loading periods.

Here is what I have. but obviously it won't return them as `"."` `".."` `"..."` it returns them in a random order. How would I return them in the correct order as loading periods?

```
public String loadingPeriods() {
    General.sleep(50);
    int num = General.random(1, 10);
    if (num > 7) {
        return ".";
    }
    if (num > 4) {
        return "..";
    }
    if (num > 0) {
        return "...";
    }
    return "...";
}
```

Comment: Please provide the output you expect and explain the logic behind it.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your requirement but maybe make "num" a static variable and increment it in each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this logic time-based to easily create loading dots (example cycles every 3s):

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() % 3000;
if (time < 1000) {
    return ".";
} else if (time < 2000) {
    return "..";
} else {
    return "...";
}
```

This approach also avoids locking the calling thread with `sleep`.